# background image pseudo quotes issue

Tags: html, css

I'm applying a background image to a pseudo element and it seems to work fine on codepen. I'm using the exact same code as below but on the website i'm working on, this rule breaks with an invalid name error.. If i inspect element and add quotes around the URL, it works.

```css
button::before {  
content: '';
display: block;
width: 22px;
height: 22px; 
background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 576 512'%3E%3Cpath d='M259.3 17.8L194 150.2 47.9 171.5c-26.2 3.8-36.7 36.1-17.7 54.6l105.7 103-25 145.5c-4.5 26.3 23.2 46 46.4 33.7L288 439.6l130.7 68.7c23.2 12.2 50.9-7.4 46.4-33.7l-25-145.5 105.7-103c19-18.5 8.5-50.8-17.7-54.6L382 150.2 316.7 17.8c-11.7-23.6-45.6-23.9-57.4 0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}
```

```html
<button class="Comment-vote-button vote-true" data-voted="false" title="Good Answer"><span class="Comment-vote-count">2</span></button>
```

It's as though the browser strips the quotes / doesn't recognise them on this site. Very strange issue. I'm stumped with it.

Comment: I have quotes in the original code too? but not recognised on the site

Comment: There's not much we can do if your code **here** works.

Comment: Ok, gunna try alternate the quotes - single on outside, double within... Thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

Change the quotes `''` inside `""` or also you can try ``